# Need to create two groups of items in foreach loop based on the number of items, but with a twist

Tags: php, loops, foreach

OK,

so I have a foreach loop in PHP.

```
$i = 0

$c = count($cars);

foreach ( $cars as $car ) {

   // if less than 10 items
   if ( $c < 10 ) {
      echo '<div class="column-full-width">';
         echo $i . '. ' . $car->name;
      echo '</div>';
      $i++;
   }
   // if 10 items or more
   if ( $c > 10 ) {
      if ( $c <= 5 ) {
         echo '<div class="column-left">';
            echo $i . '. ' . $car->name;
         echo '</div>';
         $i++;
      }
      if ( $c > 5 ) {
         echo '<div class="column-right">';
            echo $i . '. ' . $car->name;
         echo '</div>';
         $i++;
      }
   }

}
```

And I need to create 2 columns if the items in the array are 10 or more (if the are 9 max, 1 column is ok), however, the columns should be dynamically even in numbers of items that they contain... I mean if I have 10 items both columns will contain 5 items, if I have 11 items the left column will have 6 items and the right will have 5 items, if I will have 12 items both will have 6 items, if I will have 13 items, the left will have 7 and the right column will have 6 items.

How to do such condition in PHP?

Comment: Does the order matter? For example, would the first 5 go in the left and the second 5 go in the right column? Or would it be first in left, second in right, third in left, so on... ?

Comment: First of all, put the code that is inside the foreach outside of it. You need to check first and then output the html code for the columns, otherwise you keep generating columns.

Comment: Your code as it is structured right now won't work. What you have to do is this: first you check how many items you have; then based on that result you generate one or two columns. If you have two columns you just divide your items by 2 and also take the remainder. The left column will then have floor(items/2) + remainder items and the right column floor(items/2) where floor is the floor function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
$c = count($cars);

$i = 0;

if ($c < 10) {
  echo '<div class="column-full-width">';
  foreach ($cars as $car) {
     echo ($i++) . '. ' . $car->name . '<br />';
  }
  echo '</div>';
} else {
  $lc = ceil($c / 2);     
  $act = reset($cars);   

  echo '<div class="column-left">';
  while ($i < $lc) {
    echo ($i++) . '. ' . $act->name . '<br />';    
    $act = next($cars);
  }       
  echo '</div>';     

  echo '<div class="column-right">';
  while ($i < $c) {
    echo ($i++) . '. ' . $act->name . '<br />';    
    $act = next($cars);
  }   
  echo '</div>';
}
```